# Available Datasets not showing ALL my classes but will show them 1 at a time. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am using VS 2013 with SQL Server Client 2012 (SSRS Version). I have an SSRS Report and am trying to use 4 c# classes as Datasets. The SSRS Designer lets me select the classes and creates a `Properties/DataSources` for each class I import but the classes don't appear in the "Available Datasets" dropdown in the report designer's "Add DataSet" menu.

**Here are the strange things I noticed/tried:**

- if I add the classes 1-by-1 or in 2's then I can add any 2 of them and they appear in the "Available Datasets". But then if I add the 3rd class or 4th class then the "Available Datasets" stops showing the others (still shows the 1 or 2 that I added initially). All the classes I add appear in the `Properties/DataSources` directory.
- if I try to add very primitive classes I can add 4 primitive classes so it doesn't sound like the Report has a limit on the available datasets.

**Here's what I am looking for:**

1. Is there a way to find out the reason why a class doesn't appear in the 
   Available Datasets list in the Report Designer? or do you know of any reasons?
2. Is there a way to Debug the Report Designer?
3. Are there any other ideas I can try?

Comment: Any resolution to this? Still happening in vs2019